# How to get battery,cpu,memory usage using appium

Tags: android, selenium-webdriver, appium

I have developed a code to run script on Android real device using Appium server.
Now i want to know android device battery usage during script execution.
Is there any api available in appium to get battery / disk / cpu / memory usage ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use ADB to get all types of information about android device:

To check the status of usb charger and battery:

`Adb shell cat /sys/class/power_supply/usb/*`

`Adb shell cat /sys/class/power_supply/battery/*`

Get the current CPU operating speed:

```
Adb shell cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/<cpu#>/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq
```

Get the free Memory:

```
adb shell vmstat
```

Reference :
https://sites.google.com/site/adbusefulcommands/